# Syntax Errors - Pinescript Trading strategy

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

just wondering is anyone can tell me why i keep getting syntax errors with this code.

```
//@version=3
// This strategy uses consolidating market detection, breakout detection and comprehensive risk management

// The strategy uses the following indicators:
// 1. Bollinger Bands (bb) - to detect consolidating markets
// 2. Average True Range (atr) - to measure market volatility
// 3. Moving Average Convergence Divergence (macd) - to confirm breakouts

// Set up strategy variables
strategy("My Trading Strategy", overlay=true)
length = input(title="Bollinger Band Length", type=integer, defval=20)
multiplier = input(title="Bollinger Band Multiplier", type=float, defval=2.0)
atrLength = input(title="ATR Length", type=integer, defval=14)
atrMultiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=float, defval=1.5)
macdLength = input(title="MACD Length", type=integer, defval=12)
macdFastLength = input(title="MACD Fast Length", type=integer, defval=26)
macdSlowLength = input(title="MACD Slow Length", type=integer, defval=9)

// Calculate Bollinger Bands
bbTop = bollinger(close, length, multiplier)
bbBottom = bollinger(close, length, -multiplier)

// Calculate Average True Range
atrValue = atr(atrLength)

// Calculate Moving Average Convergence Divergence
macdValue = macd(close, macdFastLength, macdSlowLength, macdLength)

// Check for consolidating market
if (close > bbTop or close < bbBottom)
    strategy.close("Consolidating Market")

// Check for breakout
if (close > bbTop and macdValue > 0)
    // Long breakout
    strategy.entry("Long Breakout", strategy.long)

else if (close < bbBottom and macdValue < 0)
    // Short breakout
    strategy.entry("Short Breakout", strategy.short)

// Set stop loss and take profit
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long Breakout", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - (atrMultiplier * atrValue)), limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + (atrMultiplier * atrValue)))
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Short Breakout", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + (atrMultiplier * atrValue)), limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - (atrMultiplier * atrValue)))
```

hen i try to add it to the chart in trading view. I get the error below:

22:06:30 — Compilation error. Line 38: mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation' which relates to the else if statement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`else if` is not supported in Pinescript version 3. To do an `else if` you have to type an if statement in the else statement:

```
if (condition)

else
   if(condition)
```

I would recommend you use Pinescript version 5 instead, where they support `else if`. There they also have an inbuild Bollinger band function with `[middle, upper, lower] = ta.bb(close, 5, 4)`